# redirect to one module to another module views in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two modules in angular application. Lets say for example module A and Module B. I have some set of views in module A. when the user hits the index file of Module B, i need to redirect/show the views in the Module A

ModuleA code:

```
 define [
  'angular'
  'angularanimate'
  'angularroute'
  'jquery'
  'jquery.fileupload'


 ], (
  angular
  angularanimate
  angularroute
  $
 ) ->
 app = angular.module 'app', []



 # Routes #
 app.config ['$provide', '$routeProvider', ($provide, $routeProvider) ->


 $routeProvider
  .when "/viewC"
    redirectTo: "/view0301"
  .otherwise
    redirectTo: "/view0101"

]
```

ModuleB code :

```
define [
 'angular'
 'jquery'
 **'moduleA/app/scripts/appModuleA'** 

], (angular, $) ->
 appDev = angular.module 'appDev', ['app'] - injected the moduleA

 appDev.config ['$provide', '$routeProvider', ($provide, $routeProvider) ->
   $routeProvider
     .when "/" - Now need to redirect to the views of the moudleA
```

How to acheive this implementation? Please help me on this

Comment: You may want to check [this](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy/); it is not complete, but you may get some ideas.